# PTIJ: Why can't you turn away a baker with the king's ring?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Megillah says:

> ונחתום בטבעת המלך אין להשיב
>
> You can't turn away a baker with the king's ring

Why not?  What's special about a baker, as opposed to a butcher or a candlestick maker?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Unless the King is on a gluten-free or some other sorta diet, why would even the king himself turn away a baker? Who’d make the challah, or hamantashen, or matzah, or chunky chocolate chip cookies?

Comment: @JJLL especially since the נחתום is the guy who actually bakes the bread and cookies, as opposed to the פלטר or מנפול who buys it from the נחתום and sells it.  Demai 3:3-4

Answer (score 4):

One thing that baker's bake are donuts. Well, you can't turn away the baker that baked the world's largest donut, because he's the [Donut King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donut_King).

> On 5 December 2007, Donut King oversaw construction of the World's
>   Largest Doughnut, in order to celebrate The Simpsons Movie's DVD
>   release. It was created from over 90,000 doughnuts, using half a tonne
>   of pink icing and 30 kg of sprinkles from Donut King. Taking 40 people
>   over nine hours to build, the giant doughnut measured six metres and
>   weighed 3.5 tonnes

He used the king's ring to make that huge donut, because the king's ring was the largest ring.

Comment: Maybe "ring" is a euphemism for donut?

Comment: @DanF I couldn't stop laughing. Would have even upvoted you except that they told me my daily limit was reached. Too much pink icing